# An open set and its closure in a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional  manifold without boundary. Let $W$ be an open set of $M$ whose topological boundary is an $(n-1)$-dimensional regular submanifold of $M$. How to show that the closure $\overline{W}$ of $W$ is an $n$-dimensional manifold with boundary.

We need to show that for every $p\in\overline{W}$, there is an open set (in the subspace topology) in $\overline{W}$ homeomorphic to an open set in the half plane $H^n_+=\{x=(x^1,\dots,x^n)\in\mathbb{R}^n:x^n\geq 0\}$. If $p$ is in $W$, we can restrict the charts of $M$ to $W$ to obtain a homeomorphism, but how to deal with the points in $\partial W$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $W \subset M$ be open and $S = \partial W$. Recall that $\overline{W} = W \cup \partial W = W \cup S$. This should help you see that the closure is an $n$-manifold. To show that it has boundary consider $\{p: p \in S\}$ and since these points are in the boundary of $W$, then there must exist a collection $\{(U, \phi): U \subset M\}$ with $\phi(p) = (x^1(p),...,x^{n-1}(p),0)$ i.e $\partial \overline{W} = S$.